# Как создать SSL сертификат для личного сервера?

Tags: сервер, ssl, lamp

Вот допустим у меня есть сервер на Debian. А на нем сайт, к которому можно перейти по `http://192.168.../...`. Возможно ли сделать для него SSL сертификат? Чтобы был `https`, а не `http`?

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться бесплатными утилитами для генерации ssl-ключей
например [этой](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert)